# Is there any book or text where ionic radius of elements are given?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reference-request, solid-state-chemistry

So my research has me looking for ionic radius characterization. If anyone could post any link or give the name of any book where ionic radius of all elements are given that would be really great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "classic" work by Shannon and colleagues [[1](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740869003220), [2](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567739476001551)], also available online as [Database of Ionic Radii](http://abulafia.mt.ic.ac.uk/shannon/ptable.php).

Extended ionic radii for lanthanides with higher coordination numbers were published by Jia [[3](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(91)90388-X)].

The values from the references above are also compiled in recent editions of *CRC handbook of chemistry and physics*, e.g. [4, p. 12-12].

More recently, an updated series of calculated ionic radii has been published by Rahm et al. [[4](https://doi.org/10.1002/chem.201602949)].

#### References

1. Shannon, R. D.; Prewitt, C. T. Effective Ionic Radii in Oxides and Fluorides. *Acta Cryst B* **1969**, 25 (5), 925–946. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740869003220.
2. Shannon, R. D. Revised Effective Ionic Radii and Systematic Studies of Interatomic Distances in Halides and Chalcogenides. *Acta Cryst A* **1976**, 32 (5), 751–767. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567739476001551.
3. Jia, Y. Q. Crystal Radii and Effective Ionic Radii of the Rare Earth Ions. *Journal of Solid State Chemistry* **1991**, 95 (1), 184–187. https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(91)90388-X.
4. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; **2017**; Vol. 97.
5. Rahm, M.; Hoffmann, R.; Ashcroft, N. W. Atomic and Ionic Radii of Elements 1–96. *Chem. Eur. J.* **2016**, 22 (41), 14625–14632. https://doi.org/10.1002/chem.201602949.